# Remove HTML Elements with values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove <select>....</select> html element with all of it's it's values (option) on click event. like

```
<span>Span First</span>
<select>
<option>opt 01</option>
<option>opt 02</option>
</select>
<span>Span Second</span>
<select>
<option>opt 11</option>
<option>opt 12</option>
</select>
```

Want to output like this:

```
Span First Span Second
```

I'm using code like:

```
<script>
function removeTags(str)
{
if ((str===null) || (str===''))
return false;
else
str = str.toString();
return str.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
}
document.write(removeTags('<html> Tutorix is <script> the best <body> e-learning platform'));;
</script>
```

Above code working fine but unable to remove value inside <option>opt ..</option>

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: You haven't shown more context for your HTML, such as the parent element. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<select>` elements with `.remove()`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("select").forEach(el => el.remove());
```

```html
<span>Span First</span>
<select>
<option>opt 01</option>
<option>opt 02</option>
</select>
<span>Span Second</span>
<select>
<option>opt 11</option>
<option>opt 12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I have one more question, I have html code in my textbox1. on button click i want to parse html code from textbox1 and want to show output (Span First Span Second) in textbox2.

Comment: You are asking a brand new and completely separate question. Your original question has nothing about textboxes. You can consider using `innerHTML` javascript keyword to solve your problem. But if you can't figure it out, I suggest creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DOM's removeChild() method to remove the elements.  You can also use latest remove() method.

```
Array
 .from(parentNode.querySelectorAll('sele 
 ct').forEach((elem) => {
       parentNode.removeChild[elem]
  })
```